# How do I use impersonation on a C# Winforms application to run with admin privileges?

Tags: c#

How do I use impersonation to run a C# Winforms application with admin privileges? 
Can anyone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following line of code may help you to achieve your goal. I found this in a "Code Project" article.

check full article : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/UserImpersonationInNET.aspx

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


//the following code executed before you perform your task

if ( ! ImpersonationUtil.Impersonate( _userName, _password, _domain ) )

{
MessageBox.Show("Impersonation failed.");
return;
}

//Perform task as this user here...

//After your task, do this:
ImpersonationUtil.UnImpersonate();


Here is the code for the ImpersonationUtil class:

/// <summary>
/// Impersonate a windows logon.
/// </summary>
public class ImpersonationUtil {

/// <summary>
/// Impersonate given logon information.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="logon">Windows logon name.</param>
/// <param name="password">password</param>
/// <param name="domain">domain name</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool Impersonate( string logon, string password, string
domain ) {
WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

if( LogonUser( logon, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0 ) {

if ( DuplicateToken( token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate ) != 0 ) {
tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
if ( null != impersonationContext ) return true;
}
}

return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Unimpersonate.
/// </summary>
public static void UnImpersonate() {
impersonationContext.Undo();
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int LogonUser(
string lpszUserName,
String lpszDomain,
String lpszPassword,
int dwLogonType,
int dwLogonProvider,
ref IntPtr phToken );

[DllImport("advapi32.dll",
CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Aut o,
SetLastError=true)]
public extern static int DuplicateToken(
IntPtr hToken,
int impersonationLevel,
ref IntPtr hNewToken );

private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
private const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 4;
private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
private static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question on SO:
[How to run c# application with admin creds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916714/how-to-run-c-application-with-admin-creds)

There are some codeproject impersonation resources:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx

> Check out **WindowsIdentity** class in **System.Security.Principal**.
>
> There is an **Impersonate()** method that will do what you are trying to
> accomplish. The missing link with this class is that you have to obtain an
> access token handle to use it. The only way I know of doing this is by
> pinvoking one of the Win32 security functions like **LogonUser()**.

Source:
http://www.developmentnow.com/g/36_2005_4_0_0_511838/Run-with-Administrator-Credentials.htm

You can also set up special XML in application manifest, which will force your application to always run as an administrator.
http://www.enusbaum.com/blog/2007/08/26/how-to-run-your-c-application-as-administrator-in-windows-vista/

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want "Run as admin" you could perhaps use [`RunElevated`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282448/uac-vista-and-c-programatically-requesting-elevation/2282613#2282613)?